# How to run ansible and ansible-playbook in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ansible, ansible-2.x

I am using python 3.4 and ansible 2.0,
all my ansible tasks are working properly from command line

here i am executing a simple task:

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
  - name: Install bind
    yum: state=latest name=bind
```

my host file is :

```
S1 ansible_host=server1.jackson.com ansible_user=root ansible_private_key_file=/home/jackson/Documents/ansible/virt_server.pem
S2 ansible_host=server2.jackson.com ansible_user=root ansible_private_key_file=/home/jackson/Documents/ansible/virt_server.pem
```

I searched on youtube blogs and everywhere but no tutorial for ansible 2.X
everywhere in tutorials using `**ansible.runner**`  but in ansible 2.0 its not available.

I just want a example that teach me how to define hosts, ansible configurations, tasks, variables and how can to execute tasks.

In addition i also want to know how can I use JSON instead of .yml file, so that i can get configuration variables from database or from user input, in sort every thing in one dynamic python script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ansible Docs provides a good document for using the Python API, for both 2.0 and pre-2.0.  See http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/developing_api.html#python-api-2-0.

I did have issues getting the right version of ansible to run with the right version of python, but you can use [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) to create a virtual environment and install ansible using pip from that environment, then just try to import ansible to ensure it's working.

There are instances where JSON can be used, but the easier solution is to use a script to change YAML to JSON.

From http://yamltojson.com/#python:

```
import yaml
import json

yml = """
---
  foo: bar
"""
data = yaml.load(yml)
json = json.dumps(data)

print(json)
```

Comment: Thanks for help @Theo